# iOS: Proper way of initializing an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, class-method, instance-methods

Modeled after Parse's `PFQuery` class, I'm building my own `EMQuery` class, for my own project (not a subclass of PFQuery). My question is, if I want to perform a similar call to a class method in the manner that Parse does it (`PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWith...]`) would this be the correct approach?

```
+ (instancetype)queryWithType:(EMObjectType)objectType {
    EMQuery *query = [[self alloc] init];
    return [query initWithQueryType:objectType];
}

- (id)initWithQueryType:(EMObjectType)objectType {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - as you are calling init of the superclass twice.

Your initWithQueryType should replace the call to init

```
+ (instancetype)queryWithType:(EMObjectType)objectType {
    EMQuery *query = [self alloc];
    return [query initWithQueryType:objectType];
}
```

The exception is if the init in your class does something. In that case the two inits `init` and `initWithQueryType:` should be set up that one calls the other and the one called is the only one that calls `super init` This one is the designated initialiser

The main explanation of all initialization is the section on Object Initialization [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6)

Comment: Ahh I see. Perfect explanation! Thank you for the link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't call two init methods; call one, once. Like this:

```
+ (instancetype)queryWithType:(EMObjectType)objectType {
    EMQuery *query = [[self alloc] initWithQueryType:objectType];
    return query;
}
```

Comment: It's not that one is enough. You must call one and only one init method.